Attack squad has a special visor that shows where the "enemy" is?
We watched a movie in the last few years where an futuristic attack squad comes into a city area in a helicopter with special goggles/visors on their helmet that show them where the enemy is located.  I think I remember the "enemies" showing up in a different color (maybe in blue?) than normal people or squad-mates.  The twist is that the people the visors highlight aren't really the bad guys.  They are trained to believe their visors and are somewhat unknowingly fighting an enemy they normally wouldn't agree to fighting.
I think this was a young-adult type movie similar to Maze Runner or Divergent, and I'm pretty sure it got pretty poor reviews.  I'm pretty certain it was made in the last three years in the US, and would have been released in theaters. I don't know how big of a plot point the whole enemy highlighting visors are, but I sort of have the feeling it may have just been some introductory scene.  I don't feel like the whole movie was about just that.  I also feel like the city area was in a post-apocalyptic or at least sparsely populated state.

I'm pretty sure it's The 5th Wave, even though it came out this year.

Well, I knew it was recent, but sometimes things seem more recent than they are, so I padded to "last few years"...

The movie you are describing is "The 5th Wave", starring Chloë Grace Moretz. Here's a clip of the headsets you're remembering.




Thanks, I knew this would be an easy one, but I just couldn't remember it!  This is exactly it.  This wikia page is about the "Detection Scopes".

I only saw the movie recently, so it was more fresh in my memory. Still took a couple minutes to remember the name!

@BrettFromLA Not exactly a ringing endorsement, then... ;)
